# DataGrip Issue Load Data Local Infile

Tags: mysql-8.0, datagrip

I am having trouble using the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` statement in Datagrip. Suppose I have `source_data.csv` such as:

```
rating,statement
-2,"I'm hungry!"
5,"I'm satisfied."
1,"Ok, but could be better."
```

After running the following code block in DataGrip:

```
# loading_sample_table.sql

USE sample_db;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sample_table;
CREATE TABLE sample_table (rating int, statement varchar(50), id serial);

LOAD DATA
    LOCAL INFILE 'absolute/path/to/my/source_data.csv'
    INTO TABLE sample_table
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY  '\''
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (rating, statement);
```

I receive the following error:

`[42000][1148] The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version`

Running `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";` in either MySQL shell or DataGrip produces

```
+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                         |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
| immediate_server_version | 999999                        |
| innodb_version           | 8.0.18                        |
| original_server_version  | 999999                        |
| protocol_version         | 10                            |
| slave_type_conversions   |                               |
| tls_version              | TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3 |
| version                  | 8.0.18                        |
| version_comment          | MySQL Community Server - GPL  |
| version_compile_machine  | x86_64                        |
| version_compile_os       | macos10.14                    |
| version_compile_zlib     | 1.2.11                        |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

Then, if I try the same same command above but just drop `LOCAL` from the code block, I receive the following error:

`[HY000][13] Can't get stat of 'absolute/path/to/my/source_data.csv' (OS errno 13 - Permission denied)`

Also, I checked `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';` and can see:

```
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| local_infile  | ON    |
+---------------+-------+
```

However, if from my terminal I run:

`mysql --local-infile=1 -uroot -p < 'absolute/path/to/my/loading_sample_table.sql'`

After entering my root password, **the file runs successfully**. Ideally, I would like to do everything in DataGrip. Unsure on how to debug this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to add the following parameter to the server-side connection string and it worked without having to downgrade the driver version:

`jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?allowLoadLocalInfile=true`

Comment: Thank you, Vivek, this helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like MySQL JDBC driver issue.

Switch to MySQL JDBC driver `5.1.47` provided by DataGrip to resolve the issue.

To change JDBC Driver version:

- go to data source
- click to Mysql and select `Go to driver`
- change driver version to `5.1.47`

[image: Change JDBC Driver version]

Load data local infile result:

[image: Load infile]

Comment: While this technically works, I ideally would like to still have access to features offered in MySQL-8 such as CTE's and Analytic Functions.